# Pasar a time String

Tags: sql, sql-server

COmo puedo pasar este resultado a Time en sql server.

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(T2.TimeWeek) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(FLOOR((((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 3600) / 60)) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 60) AS VARCHAR), 2) AS [Hours total]
```

Esto me da un resultado asi "00:00:00" como lo puedo convertir a time para que el resultado se 00:00:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @tiempo VARCHAR(50);

--El valor que devuelto "00:00:00" lo almacenamos en una variable para fines prácticos del ejemplo
SET @tiempo = ... RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(T2.TimeWeek) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(FLOOR((((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 3600) / 60)) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 60) AS VARCHAR), 2)) ... ;

SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @tiempo) AS hoursTotal;
```

Si lo anterior no funciona, también puedes intentar con:

```
SELECT CAST(@tiempo AS TIME) AS hoursTotal;
```

CONVERT y CAST se utilizan para convertir datos de su tipo original a otro tipo de datos.

Solo existen 2 diferencias fundamentales entre utilizar CAST o CONVERT para convertir tipos de datos:

- CAST es soportado por el estándar ANSI mientras CONVERT no lo es.
- CONVERT soporta tipo de datos de fecha (date, datetime, etc.)
  mientras CAST no, es decir, con CAST no se pueden modificar tipos de
  datos de fecha.

Realice la prueba con CONVERT y funcionó, lo convirtió a tipo TIME, pero no se muestra 00:00:00.0000000 como tu quieres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual forma, hice la prueba con CAST y realizó la conversión a tipo TIME, pero no se muestra 00:00:00.0000000.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que al menos sea de tu ayuda en algo, ¡suerte!.

Comment: no logro obtener el dato esperado